# Condition does not give excepted output in Nested array in React

Tags: reactjs

I want to display image if(user.id===follow.self_id) other wise I want to display the

## Notuser

Plz help me to carry out this output Iam using Nested array map of react. This code works fine but cannot expected output .. It display the both image and text .But i want to display particular one based on condition.. Plz help me

```
                           <table className="table table-bordered">
                  <thead>
                     <tr>
                               <th scope="col">First</th>
                              <th scope="col">Follow</th>

                   </tr>
                 </thead>
        <tbody>

 

               {
                        loading.load==true &&
                         form.users.map((user) => {

                            return(
                <tr>
                           <td>{user.name}</td>
                           <span> </span>
                          {follow.follows.map((follow) => {

                             return(

                    <div>
                              {user.id===follow.self_id&&
                        <td><img src={require('../../follo.png')} onClick={()=>Friend(user.id)}/> 
                           </td>
                                }
                  </div>

                               )}

                          <td><h1>Not user</h2></td>

                                )}
                                 </tr>
                              );
                               })
                               }  
   </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: Format your code.

Comment: Please review your english and code formatting. No abbreviation like `plz`.

Answer (score -1):

You should include headline inside map:

```
follow.follows.map((follow) => 
    <div>
      {user.id===follow.self_id ? 
        <img src={require('../../follo.png')} onClick={()=>Friend(user.id)}/> : 
        <h1>Not user</h1>
      }
    </div>
    )
```

Comment: Impossible, you're doing something wrong. Show more code, on codesandbox if it's possible.

Comment: Not user  will display more than one time ... based on iterations bro ...